# Why does a custom element collapse?

Tags: html, svg, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I try to define a custom field, containing either a SVG or a Canvas. But my example shows some strange rendering. I expect two boxes 400 pixel wide and 300 pixel high. But both boxes seem to  collapse in different ways. How can I fix this?

```js
class TestSvg extends HTMLElement
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const container = document.createElement('svg');
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
    shadow.appendChild (container);
  }
}

class TestCanvas extends HTMLElement
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const container = document.createElement('canvas');
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
    shadow.appendChild (container);
  }
}

customElements.define ('test-svg', TestSvg);
customElements.define ('test-canvas', TestCanvas);
```

```css
test-svg, test-canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
svg
<test-svg>
</test-svg>
canvas
<test-canvas>
</test-canvas>
end
```

Same without custom elements:

```css
svg, canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
svg
<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>
canvas
<canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>
end
```

Why is there a difference between the version with custom elements and the version without custom elements?

Comment: there are 2 400x300 boxes w/o custom elements, because the browser recognizes svg and canvas.

Comment: @curveball And why are they not recognized as a part of a custom element?

Comment: you cannot create SVG elements with createElement you need to use createElementNS and specify the SVG namespace as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your SVG element is not being created correctly.  It needs to be in the correct SVG namespace. Change it to this:

   ```
   const container = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
   ```
2. By default, your custom elements will be `display: inline`.  Set them to `block` or `inline-block` depending on your need.

   ```
   test-svg, test-canvas {
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }
   ```

Updated test:

```js
class TestSvg extends HTMLElement
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const container = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
    shadow.appendChild (container);
  }
}

class TestCanvas extends HTMLElement
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const container = document.createElement('canvas');
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
    shadow.appendChild (container);
  }
}

customElements.define ('test-svg', TestSvg);
customElements.define ('test-canvas', TestCanvas);
```

```css
test-svg, test-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
svg
<test-svg>
</test-svg>
canvas
<test-canvas>
</test-canvas>
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to see more people are combining Custom Elements and SVG, they are a [good match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315681/how-can-i-draw-a-pie-chart-only-using-stroke-dasharray-not-stroke-dashoffset/65328524#65328524)

Your core problem was the SVG NameSpace, so Paul his answer is correct.

Some additional comments:

Your constructor can be optimized:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const container = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
    shadow.appendChild (container);
  }
```

- `super()` returns the element scope
  Google documentation that says to use `super()` **first** is wrong,
  they mean: Call `super()` **before** you can use the 'this' scope reference.
- `attachShadow()` boths  sets AND returns `this.shadowRoot` for free
- `.appendChild()` returns the created element

So you can chain everything:

```js
constructor() {
    const container = super()
                        .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
                        .appendChild (document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg'));
    container.setAttribute('width', '400');
    container.setAttribute('height', '300');
  }
```

If you do not do anything special with this **in memory** Custom Element,
you can scrap the whole `constructor` and create the element with HTML in the `connectedCallback`

```js
connectedCallback(){
  this.innerHTML = `<svg width='400' height='300' 
                         xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
                         viewBox='0 0 20 20'></svg>`;
}
```

Note: I also ditched shadowDOM above; if you do want shadowDOM its:

```js
connectedCallback(){
  this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = `<svg width='400' height='300' 
                         xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
                         viewBox='0 0 20 20'></svg>`;
}
```

#### There is another sizing problem

Depending on your Font family and size there will be a gutter below your **inline-block** SVG Custom Element (see RED below) to allow for **pgjq** characters that stick out below the base line.

[image]

To counter that you have to set `vertical-align: top` on the SVG element:

```html
<style>
  body { font-size: 3em }
  svg-circle { background: RED }

  svg-circle svg {
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
  }
  #correct svg { vertical-align: top }
</style>
<div>
  <svg-circle radius="40%" color="green"></svg-circle>
  <svg-circle x="50%" y="100%" color="blue"></svg-circle>
  <svg-circle></svg-circle>
</div>
<div id="correct">
  <svg-circle radius="40%" color="green"></svg-circle>
  <svg-circle x="50%" y="100%" color="blue"></svg-circle>
  <svg-circle></svg-circle>
</div>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() { return ["x", "y", "radius", "color"] }
    connectedCallback()             { this.render() }
    attributeChangedCallback()      { this.render() }
    render() {
      let [x = "50%",y = "50%",radius = "50%", color = "rebeccapurple"] = 
        this.constructor.observedAttributes.map(x => this.getAttribute(x) || undefined);
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox='0 0 96 96'>
                          <circle cx='${x}' cy='${y}' r='${radius}' fill='${color}'/></svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Note: There is no shadowDOM attached to `<svg-circle>`, so the SVG inside can be styled with **global** CSS

#### Make it an IMG

If you do not want any CSS bleeding, and want to work with the SVG as if it is an image,
without [pointer-events](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/) issues, then create an IMG:

```js
this.innerHTML = `<img src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 96 96'>
                       <circle cx='${x}' cy='${y}' r='${radius}' fill='${color}'/>
                       </svg>">`.replace(/#/g, "%23");
```

Note: The **#** is the only character that needs to be escaped here. In CSS `url()` usage you also need to escape the **<** and **>**

#### Add a grid

If you are going to create an Icon Toolbar or Chessboard like layout with SVGs, add a grid:

```css
  #correct {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  }

  svg-circle svg {
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first custom element `TestSvg`, change the element type from **svg** to **canvas**

```
const container = document.createElement('canvas');
```

HTML elements reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

'canvas' is an HTML element.
where as 'svg' is not. 'svg' is Container element, structure element

Comment: I did it in `TestCanvas` and it does not work either.

Comment: Why? You can copy it to your answer.

Comment: Ok. thats what I did, yo need to modify TestSVG class

Comment: In both custom elements "TestSVG" and "TestCanvas", the element type should be "canvas"

Comment: No! TestSvg should feature a SVG and TestCanvas should feature a Canvas.

Comment: Look at the valid HTML elements , link provided in answer

Comment: `svg` is also a valid element: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Comment: may be you can try <img>, if you want or render in <canvas> it self

Comment: I doubt if "document.createElement" can take <svg>.  The <svg> is not classified in HTML elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: Scrolldown in the link you posted in comments for 'svg' element. you can see that it is classified as Container element, structure element.